# How to make a proper alternate row color on a filtered TVirtualStringTree

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

Previously I used this `VirtualStringTree` for showing all of the nodes, and I used the `Node.Index` to check the odd and even rows inside the `OnBeforeCellPaint` event.

But when I filtered the nodes, I realized that the `Node.Index` is irrelevant to be used as alternate rows as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: VirtualStringTree alternate color on filtered nodes]

Any idea/solution to solve this?

Comment: `Node.Index` is the index of node with regard to its parent. what is the desired output? what code do you use? maybe you need to take `GetNodeLevel` into account.

Comment: @kobik: I assume he or she wants to have an alternating white and slightly darker background for each displayed row. That could prove complicated when some nodes are expanded and some are not, because I assume that that would not redraw the total of visible nodes.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, I'm not sure expanding nodes is the issue here. I **assume** OP is hiding some nodes (aka "Filtered"), and is after a *pseudo* `Node.VisibleIndex`.

Comment: Yes, I guess he is indeed looking for something like `VisibleIndex`, and whether it is odd or even, no matter if nodes are expanded or not. But if nodes are expanded, this could mean that for any lines below, the backgrund colour should change.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, Yes but that would be easy to solve with `GetNodeLevel == 0`. OP did not show any code - how he populates nodes? how does the filter works?.

Comment: As you can see on my screenshot, My alternate row color went wrong because I was using `Node.Index` as a reference.

When we are using Filter on that VirtualStringTree, some of the nodes are hiding, but the index remains the same. I used filter as: `VST.IsFiltered[Node] := [some condition]`. And that's why some nodes are hidden.

I think what @kobik and @RudyVelthuis was right. I am looking for something like `VisibleIndex`. But rather than modifying the component to provide something like that, maybe you have some other workaround.

Comment: By the way, I only use the 1st level node to draw this alternate color. The issue is not related with expanded node.

Comment: You will need to implement GetVisibleIndex yourself. Its not that difficult. Simply iterate nods and inc count for nodes having vsVisible state until you find taget node. Btw in my VT version there is no IsFiltered property.

Comment: I see. No choice then. I have to modify the VST component. Fyi, I'm still using VirtualStringTree v5.2.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color VirtualStringTree rows with hidden nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428920/color-virtualstringtree-rows-with-hidden-nodes)

Answer (score -1):

```
procedure TMainForm.IpTreeBeforeCellPaint(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
  CellPaintMode: TVTCellPaintMode; CellRect: TRect; var ContentRect: TRect);
begin
  if Node.Index mod 2 = 0
  then  TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $00F7E6D5
  else  TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $00FBF2EA;

  if Sender = ipTree then
    if IpAddresses[ PVirtualNode( Node ).Index ].Highlighted then         
TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;

  TargetCanvas.FillRect( CellRect );
end;
```

Heres my code, this doesnt take into account child nodes.  It alternates color for each row.  However, if you did have children, you can always use

```
iLevel := Sender.GetNodeLevel( Node );
```

then if its an even number, paint all the child nodes the same as parent.

Comment: What happens if the second row is filtered out? If you read the question, you'll see this is exactly what not works.